# phpMyAdmin - How to log out on refresh page (F5)?

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, ampps

I am using `AMPPS` as a `WAMP` stack on `Windows`. I want to enable logout form when user press `F5` in phpMyAdmin. Is it possible to enable this in `config.inc.php` file?

Could you show how to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused here. Do you want to override the page reload functionality and make F5 a hotkey for the logout functionality, or you want to prevent users from being able to reload the page? If it's the second one, why — what's the difference if a user pressed the reload key or navigates to another page and back to the one they were on? For that matter, in phpMyAdmin most pages can be "reloaded" by clicking the same link again; from the Designer page if you press the Designer link again, it takes you back to the Designer page again in what looks to the user to be no different than pressing F5. I'm confused about what you're trying to prevent here.

F5 is the keyboard shortcut to reload a page, so your browser sends the same authentication token to the server and just requests the page again. phpMyAdmin can't tell from the request whether it's because the user is trying to navigate to another page or reloading the page, all it knows is that the browser has correctly authenticated and is requesting a particular page. There's no configuration directive that would change this behavior.

Maybe I'll have a different answer once you clarify what you're trying to accomplish, but as you've asked it above this is not a setting that you can enable.